# I'm trying to capture some text contents from a HTML file, and populate it to another HTML file using Javascript, but why my codes don't work?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two HTML files, and I want to change the content of one HTML file by the content of another one. Here are the code segments:

original.html:

```
<p id="old_1">this is old data</p>
```

new.html:

```
<textarea id="new_1" rows="8" cols="80"  style="width:100% !important;"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="popData()" id="button_1" value="Send" style="width:100% !important;"/>
```

I also have a separate js file with function:

```
function popData()
{
var newContent=document.getElementById("new_1").value;
document.getElementById("old_1").innerHTML=newContent;
}
```

When I write some thing in the text area, and click the button, the function popData() is called, but when I come back to the original.html, nothing has been changed. Do I need to use PHP? Is it possible to implement it with Javascript and HTML only? And no Iframe.

Comment: what do you mean by coming back to `original.html` ? they are on seperated pages?

Comment: I just want to see the content has been replaced by what I input in the textarea on browser

Comment: they should be in the same file to work, otherwise, the js code when rendered will search for this element `new_1` in the same page & will not find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As these are two separate html files, there is no means of data flow between them.

`document.getElementById("new_1").value` should work fine if both `textarea` and `<p>` tag is on a single html file.

Comment: so does this mean I have to use php? thx

Comment: If the need is to just use HTML and JS, you can leverage browsers `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` APIs. On button click use `localStorage.setItem('label', 'value')` and then on the original.html use `localStorage.getItem('label')`

Comment: thank you so much! using php is not an issue.